# Convert Date Against Where Clause

Tags: sql

I have Following dummy table with data:

```
ACID        srno    date(mm/dd/yyyy)    name
3            1     04/12/2010          mahesh
3            2     04/12/2010          mahendra
```

Now if I try with Following SQL Transact:

```
select srno from dummy
where name = 'mahesh'
and date= convert(datetime,'12/04/2010',101) –- I have date in dd/MM/yyyy Format
and ACID=3
```

It’s Not returning the srno of the table.  That means Date is not execute convert statement as above
What’s the reason?

Comment: The `dummy.date` column is a datetime datatype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using style 103 instead of 101.

```
select srno from dummy
where name = 'mahesh'
and date= convert(datetime,'12/04/2010',103) –- I have date in dd/MM/yyyy Format
and ACID=3
```

Comment: @mahesh, The 103 describes the format of your input value.  101 doesn't describe the input correctly.

Comment: Just keep in mind that 103 uses slashes, e.g. 25/12/2010, while 104 uses dots, e.g. 25.12.2010

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli, The SQL Database store the date in mm/dd/yyyy Order and I have date in 12/04/2010 --dd/mm/yyyy order than why the above statement require 103 instead of 101. what is the reason?

Comment: @Joe, You are right but still I have confusion why? if sql-server data store in mm/dd/yyyy format than for mm/dd/yyyy code is 101 ok? and dd/mm/yyyy format is 103

Comment: @mahesh: SQL is not really storing the date in mm/dd/yyyy format behind the scenes. The style chosen for the convert needs to match the format of your input value (dd/MM/yyyy).

Comment: ... if my input is in dd/mm/yyyy order than your suggested format code 103 is doing well fine. but still I have confusion about conversion code as above

Answer (score 2):

If you convert `12/04/2010` using format `101`, you get date "December 4, 2010", which is not in your database. Use format `103` to convert a date in format `dd/mm/yyyy` to `DateTime`.

The database stores dates using the DateTime type which is format-agnostic. It does have a default format for string conversions, which seems to be mm/dd/yyyy (101) on your database.

However, when you convert a string to add it to your table, you want to specify the format of your *input* string, in your example dd/mm/yyyy (103).

Take a look at the [MSDN article for CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) which details all format styles that you can use with dates.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, if you want to specify a DATE LITERAL in SQL Server, please stick with the simplest YYYYMMDD format, e.g.

```
and dummy.date = '20100412'
```

It is **robust** and works for all regional, user **language** and **dateformat** settings.  This assumes the other side of the comparison is already a date column.  Even if you had to CAST it, using this format you don't need to specify a format

```
and dummy.date = cast('20100412' as datetime)
```

Comment: Yes it's true but if some where in country like India there is pattern of date is like dd/MM/yyyy format and as per your suggestion I have to first cast or convert to YYYYMMDD than it should be work

Comment: @mahesh you may have missed the point. SQL server dates are not stored with any "format". What *you* format is the input (literal) to compare against what is stored in the column.  If you are taking input from a user or screen, then you should be using query parameters, which also doesn't care about formatting.

Comment: thanks but must understand well your comment like SQL server dates are not stored with any "format"

Comment: ... if it is true than why there is datetime datatype is available?. if it is true than why in database table shows like in MM/DD/YYYY format. I mean If i insert the date of DD/MM/YYYY format via 103 code format than it is automatically stored as MM/DD/YYYY format Why?